# Memcached/APC will not start with PHP 

Tags: php, nginx

I've compiled PHP 5.3.9 and NGINX 1.0.11 and want to use APC and Memcached with PHP. I keep getting this error when attempting to load the APC/Memcached modules:

```
Unknown(0) : Warning - PHP Startup: memcached: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20090626,NTS
PHP compiled with build ID=API20090626,NTS,debug
These options need to match
```

I tried recompiling (configure, make, make install) PHP without the --enable-debug option, but still no luck. Any ideas on what I need to do to get these options to match?

Answer (score 2):

This error was resolved by compiling a new version (5.3.10) of PHP without the `--enable-debug` option.

Comment: you should give your answer the check